# Chrome extension block using webrequest API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm working on a Chrome extension that blocks all webpages except a set list chosen by the user. I haven't had too much experience in Chrome Extensions or JavaScript for that matter.

The goal is to have the blocking script run when the user sets the amount of time in the popup and clicks submit. So on submit by the user in the popup I am trying to block web requests for a set amount of time until an alarm created by the alarm API is fired.

Right now I am ignoring the whitelist and just trying to get the webrequest blocking to work properly. Currently, it seems like the code only runs when inspecting the popup. I suspect that the script is only running properly when the popup is open. I think the problem is the architecture because I am running this from the background.js. Any guidance on a better way of handling this would be great.

Here's the important parts of my code:

manifest.json

```
  "browser_action": 
  {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Start being productive!"
  },


  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking",
                  "https://www.google.com/*", 
                  "alarms",
                  "activeTab"],

  "background": 
  {
    "scripts": ["whitelist.js", "background.js"]
  }
```

popup.html

```
 <body>
    <h1>Productivity Time</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <form id="whitelist">
        <input type="text" class="white_list" id="sites" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter URLs of websites to be whitelisted"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br></br>  
    <div id="container">
        <form id="timer">
          <span>Set Timer: </span>
          <input type="number" id="minutes" min="0" step="1" max="45">Minutes</input>
          <input type="submit" value="Start!"></input>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="whitelist.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>

  </body>
```

background.js

```
// Event handler to make alarm and start blocking
document.getElementById('timer').addEventListener('submit', blockingScript);

function blockingScript(event) {
    // Clear previous alarms
    chrome.alarms.clearAll();

    // Check that user selected a time
    if (document.getElementById('minutes').value == '')
    {
        alert("Please set time");
    }

    // Alarm will fire when user set amount of time has elapsed
    let delay = parseFloat(document.getElementById('minutes').value);
    alert(delay);
    chrome.alarms.create("alarm", {delayInMinutes: delay});

    // Block URLs
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
            {urls: ["https://www.google.com/*"]},
            ["blocking"]);
}
```

Comment: You're including the same script both in the background page and in the popup so it runs twice. The popup is a separate window that runs code only while shown. Use separate scripts. Also make sure to read the [extensions overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Oh right. I shouldn't be calling the background script in the popup html. Thanks for catching that. I have read over it but I'm still not sure whats the best way to go about achieving my goal. I'm thinking maybe a content script and using messaging to talk with the background?